my kotlin android widget doesnt update after pressing specified buttons
im making a widget that basically shows different menus breakfast lunch and dinner . Im in the initial stages and im trying to update the text on pressing nextbutton . i have a test array from which my widget should get its data from ,but it doesn't update even after pressing my button .
package com.example.daynite

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.util.Log

import android.widget.RemoteViews

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
const val UPDATE_IMAGE = "UPDATE_IMAGE"
const val PREF_NAME = "PREF_NAME"
const val INDEX_VAL = "INDEX_VAL"
class Menuwidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences
    var testlist = arrayOf("hi zacro", "this is your lunch menu", "this is your dinner menu")
    var listindex = 0

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    fun setpage(context: Context,index:Int){
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0)
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putInt(INDEX_VAL, index)
        editor.apply()
        Log.d("widgetLearning", "saved count ")

    }
    fun getpage(context: Context): Int {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0)

        return prefs.getInt(INDEX_VAL,0)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        context ?: return
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        if("UPDATE_IMAGE"==intent?.action){
            val appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra("appWidgetId",0)
            val buttonClicked = intent.getIntExtra("buttonclicked",0)

            if(buttonClicked==1){
                listindex-=1
                setpage(context,listindex)

            }
            else if (buttonClicked==2){
                listindex+=1
                setpage(context,listindex)

            }

            updateAppWidget(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), appWidgetId)

    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int
) {
    val intent = Intent(context,Menuwidget::class.java)
    intent.action = "UPDATE_IMAGE"
    intent.putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
    intent.putExtra("buttonClicked", 0)
    val pendingIntentPrev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        0,
        Intent(context, Menuwidget::class.java).apply {
            action = UPDATE_IMAGE
            putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
            putExtra("buttonClicked", 1) // Previous button
        },
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    val pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        1,
        Intent(context, Menuwidget::class.java).apply {
            action = UPDATE_IMAGE
            putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
            putExtra("buttonClicked", 2) // Next button
        },
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.menuwidget)
    var currentindex = getpage(context)
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.prevbtn, pendingIntentPrev)
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.nextbtn, pendingIntentNext)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.maintext, testlist[currentindex])
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    Log.d("WidgetLearning", "updateAppWidget: Widget updated")
    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView,R.drawable.pic2)

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}}

my xml data is
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Widget.Daynite.AppWidget.Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_blue_200"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Daynite.AppWidgetContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maintext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maintext"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maintext"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Button2" />
</RelativeLayout>


in a different code example i did it works fine with numbers and an error occurs where if i remove the widget from homescreen and add it again it stops updating .
i tried using regular variables to store the listindex , then i stuck to using sharedprefrences . i also tried learning about viewflipper but i turns out i cant use it for this . i was expecting it to change the array index when i press the button which in-turn changes the text on textview .
